# error: ‘pthread’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

i am trying compiling my project but seeing the following error.

code :  RESTServer.h

```
#ifndef __RESTSERVER__
#define __RESTSERVER__

#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

class RESTServer{
    private:
            RESTServer();
            ~RESTServer();
    public:
            static pthread *thread;
            static void init_rest_server();
};
#endif
```

Error :

```
RESTServer.h:14:10: error: ‘pthread’ does not name a type
   static pthread *thread;
```

I am trying to declare a pointer to pthread as a member of C++ class. Can anyone pls help me here.

Comment: Does your pthreads documentation mention `pthread` being a type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html); the opaque type is `pthread_t` (not `pthread*`) for thread handle.

BTW, hoping that you use some good C++11 -or C++14- implementation (e.g. [GCC 5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) or [GCC 6](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/) on Linux) you should consider using [C++11 threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) library, i.e.  [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: Thank you , very silly of me to ask this question in haste.